# How do I create a mysql client docker container that executes a mysql script against another mysql server container?

Tags: mysql, docker

How do I create a mysql client docker container that executes a mysql script against another mysql server container? Which base container should I use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can really use many different base images. Which one you use only changes how to install mysql client.

You could use debian like so

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mysql-client
CMD mysql {mysql-client-options} < {sql.script}
```

If using alpine, you just change the install to use `apk` instead

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && \
    apk add mysql-client
CMD mysql {mysql-client-options} < {sql.script}
```